# Is there an efficient, lazy way to fuse foldMap with traverse?

Tags: haskell, traversal, fold

A recent proposal on the Haskell libraries mailing list led me to consider the following:

```
ft :: (Applicative f, Monoid m, Traversable t)
   -> (b -> m) -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f m
ft f g xs = foldMap f <$> traverse g xs
```

I noticed that the `Traversable` constraint can be weakened to `Foldable`:

```
import Data.Monoid (Ap (..))  -- Requires a recent base version

ft :: (Applicative f, Monoid m, Foldable t)
   -> (b -> m) -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f m
ft f g = getAp . foldMap (Ap . fmap f . g)
```

In the original proposal, `f` was supposed to be `id`, leading to

```
foldMapA
  :: (Applicative f, Monoid m, Foldable t)
   -> (a -> f m) -> t a -> f m
--foldMapA g = getAp . foldMap (Ap . fmap id . g)
foldMapA g = getAp . foldMap (Ap . g)
```

which is strictly better than the traverse-then-fold approach.

But in the more general `ft`, there's a potential problem: `fmap` could be expensive in the `f` functor, in which case the fused version could potentially be more expensive than the original!

The usual tools for dealing with expensive `fmap` are `Yoneda` and `Coyoneda`. Since we need to lift many times and only lower once, `Coyoneda` is the one that can help us:

```
import Data.Functor.Coyoneda

ft' :: (Applicative f, Monoid m, Foldable t)
    => (b -> m) -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f m
ft' f g = lowerCoyoneda . getAp
  . foldMap (Ap . fmap f . liftCoyoneda . g)
```

So now we replace all those expensive `fmap`s with one (buried in `lowerCoyoneda`). Problem solved? Not quite.

The trouble with `Coyoneda` is that its `liftA2` is *strict*. So if we write something like

```
import Data.Monoid (First (..))

ft' (First . Just) Identity $ 1 : undefined
-- or, importing Data.Functor.Reverse,
ft' (Last . Just) Identity (Reverse $ 1 : undefined)
```

then it will fail, whereas `ft` has no trouble with those. Is there a way to have our cake and eat it too? That is, a version that uses only a `Foldable` constraint, only `fmap`s O(1) times more than `traverse` in the `f` functor, and is just as lazy as `ft`?

---

Note: we could make `liftA2` for `Coyoneda` *somewhat* lazier:

```
liftA2 f m n = liftCoyoneda $
  case (m, n) of
    (Coyoneda g x, Coyoneda h y) -> liftA2 (\p q -> f (g p) (h q)) x y
```

This is enough to let it produce an answer to `ft' (First . Just) Identity $ 1 : 2 : undefined`, but not to `ft' (First . Just) Identity $ 1 : undefined`. I don't see any obvious way to make it lazier than that, because pattern matches on existentials must always be strict.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible. Avoiding `fmap`s at the elements seems to require some knowledge of the structure of the container. For example, the `Traversable` instance for lists can be written

```
traverse f (x : xs) = liftA2 (:) (f x) (traverse f xs)
```

We know that the first argument of `(:)` is a single element, so we can use `liftA2` to combine the process of mapping over the action for that element with the process of combining the result of that action with the result associated with the rest of the list.

In a more generic context, the structure of a fold can be captured faithfully using a magma type with a bogus `Monoid` instance:

```
data Magma a = Bin (Magma a) (Magma a) | Leaf a | Nil
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Semigroup (Magma a) where
  (<>) = Bin
instance Monoid (Magma a) where
  mempty = Nil

toMagma :: Foldable t => t a -> Magma a
toMagma = foldMap Leaf
```

We can write

```
ft'' :: (Applicative f, Monoid m, Foldable t)
   => (b -> m) -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f m
ft'' f g = fmap (lowerMagma f) . traverse g . toMagma

lowerMagma :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Magma a -> m
lowerMagma f (Bin x y) = lowerMagma f x <> lowerMagma f y
lowerMagma f (Leaf x) = f x
lowerMagma _ Nil = mempty
```

But there's trouble in the `Traversable` instance:

```
traverse f (Leaf x) = Leaf <$> f x
```

That's exactly the sort of trouble we were trying to avoid. And there's no lazy fix for it. If we encounter `Bin l r`, we can't *lazily* determine whether `l` or `r` are leaves. So we're stuck. If we allowed a `Traversable` constraint on `ft''`, we could capture the result of *traversing* with a richer sort of magma type (such as one used in `lens`), which I *suspect* could let us do something more clever though I haven't found anything yet.